# Using HTTP DELETE method to cancel an action in progress

Tags: api, rest, http

**Background:**

I provide a programming interface for people who wish to place orders using my site.

They can use `GET` and `POST` methods on `/api/v1/orders` to place an order and to view list of all orders placed by them. They can also use the `GET` metod on `/api/v1/orders/<order_id>` in order to view specific details of one order.

There is a need to provide a way to cancel an order, however the records themselves need to be kept.

I would like to get feedback from more seasoned developers on whether it would be a sane decision to:

**a)** implement the `DELETE` verb on `/api/v1/current_orders/<order_id>`, which would delete it from the list of "current" orders (by marking it as cancelled). The downside is that it will make use of a different noun, which may be confusing.

**b)** implement the `DELETE` verb on `/api/v1/orders/<order_id>` with the same functionality as in a). This is somewhat misleading, as the entity will not really be deleted, and the consumer should be aware of that.

**c)** implement the `POST` verb on `/api/v1/cancellations/<order_id>` (or `POST` on `/api/v1/cancellations` with the order_id in the JSON payload). This seems to be less than ideal because a resource will not be created as a result of that request. However, the consequences of using this endpoint seem to be clearer.

**d)** ...?

**Question:**

I am aware that there is not always a "perfect" solution to designing endpoints for a REST API, but keeping in mind the need for *clarity* and *intuitiveness* and with a high regard for *best practices*, ***which of the options is "optimal"***?

Answer (score 8):

What about `PATCH` verb on `/api/v1/orders/<order_id>` indicating that it is cancelled?

[HTTP PATCH](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789) : Allows to do partial modifications in an entity. While POST creates a new one, and PUT replaces an existing one, PATCH just updates the properties you are sending, leaves the rest at they are.

You would need only to send something like `{ isCancelled:true}` as  `HTTP PATCH`, then your code would update the entity and take action like cancel any outstanding work.